# Fetch parameter from Json format data

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I need to extract `pgeextreftype`, a third level parameter, from my Lambda event.

Log of the Lambda event:

```
[INFO]  2023-04-11T09:55:18.315Z    ad6b04b5-a73a-4f41-91cb-e357b21783d6    event = {'resource': '/workorder/task', 'path': '/workorder/task', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'headers': 
 'body': '{n   "taskid": 120,\n   "wonum": "F10131266",
\n   "workorder":[\n  {\n         "pgeextreftype": "PWRPREL",\n         "pgeextreftype_description": "PowerPartner secondary workorder type",
\n         "pgeextrefvalue": "50078000002yR7fAAE",\n         "pgenonstdhrs": false,\n         "pgeppwomod": false,
\n         "pgetransmission": false\n      }\n   ]\n}', 'isBase64Encoded': False}
```

I have tried the following, but all return null:

```py
event_body.get('pgeextreftype')
event_body_workorder.get('pgeextreftype')
event_body.get('workorder.pgeextreftype')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the Json stored under the `"body"` key:

```py
import json

event = {
    "resource": "/workorder/task",
    "path": "/workorder/task",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": "xxx",
    "body": """{\n   "taskid": 120,\n   "wonum": "F10131266",
\n   "workorder":[\n  {\n         "pgeextreftype": "PWRPREL",\n         "pgeextreftype_description": "PowerPartner secondary workorder type",
\n         "pgeextrefvalue": "50078000002yR7fAAE",\n         "pgenonstdhrs": false,\n         "pgeppwomod": false,
\n         "pgetransmission": false\n      }\n   ]\n}""",
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
}

body = json.loads(event["body"])
print(body['workorder'][0]['pgeextreftype'])
```

Prints:

```
PWRPREL
```